# Measuring total amount of a program's network traffic

Tags: linux, bash, testing, tcp, tcpdump

my problem is the following:

I have many small programs and need to know huch much data they transfer over the network.
The communication uses tcp/ip.  the ports and ips are known to me beforehand.

Basically i would want to measure transferred data similar to the way "time" measures time, only with an output something like

```
sent:     3.5 kB 
received: 4.2 kB
```

instead of time measurements.

Im sure there is a way to do this, but all programs I found either just gave me packages (like `tcpdump`) oder are interactively showing bandwidth utilization.

Bandwidth does not help me, because simply summing bandwith measurements over the runtime is inprecisice.

The main problem I am having with `tcpdump` is, that I am working on client, but I can only capture on the server. So what I have tried, is an approach like

```
ssh -t server "sudo tcpdump > capture &" 
time ./my-program
ssh -t server "sudo killall tcpdump"
./evaluate.sh capture
```

But this is obviously horribly bad and I don't really know how to automize that

Currently I have giant 200+ lines Bash-script, that already takes care of measuring the runtimes for benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

On a recent benchmarking exercise, I derived LAN (and WiFi) traffic from System Activity Reporter (SAR -n), example follows. In Unix days there was a timex command, same as time but plus performance stats.

```
Receive rx, Transmit tx, Packets pck, kBytes kB, Second s
32 samples of 15 seconds

sar -n DEV 15 32 > sarLAN.txt
Linux 3.6.11+ (raspberrypi)     11/13/13        _armv6l_        (1 CPU)

12:28:11        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:28:26           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:28:26         eth0   2379.33   4569.33    125.83   6707.79      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:28:26        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:28:41           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:28:41         eth0   2518.92   4849.10    133.20   7116.48      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:28:41        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:28:56           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:28:56         eth0   2570.87   4930.40    135.89   7239.40      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:28:56        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:29:11           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:29:11         eth0   2554.27   4902.67    135.05   7193.76      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:29:11        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:29:26           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:29:26         eth0   2557.67   4904.00    135.22   7200.33      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:29:26        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:29:41           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:29:41         eth0   2561.47   4926.00    135.40   7229.17      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:29:41        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:29:56           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:29:56         eth0   4585.99   4631.51   4258.49   4997.67      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:29:56        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:30:11           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:30:11         eth0   8790.71   3855.80  12874.08    295.61      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:30:11        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:30:26           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:30:26         eth0   8897.89   3852.35  13031.29    294.89      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:30:26        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:30:41           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:30:41         eth0   8777.32   3911.69  12855.82    299.43      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:30:41        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:30:56           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:30:56         eth0   8723.85   3787.77  12768.92    289.70      0.00      0.00      0.00

12:30:56        IFACE   rxpck/s   txpck/s    rxkB/s    txkB/s   rxcmp/s   txcmp/s  rxmcst/s
12:31:11           lo      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:31:11         eth0   8636.87   3736.11  12646.58    285.77      0.00      0.00      0.00
```